# How do I write such a random source code generator?

Tags: python, random, combinations

In short, the bottom line is that I want to write a python program that generates random source code, and there is a kind of conditional image of how to do this for a full understanding imagine that programming is a rubik's cube, and that the blocks of source code are the lines "if","while","break", "def", and etc. which are cubes, and moving the blocks like cubes in a Rubik's cube, we get the source code, at the input the program receives an array of numbers in which odd numbers are the number of the block in the Rubik's cube, and even numbers are how much this block of the previous number of the block moves, and as a result, the function reads all the movement of all blocks over all the numbers of the array and ends on the last even number of the last move, which is the side of the Rubik's cube in which it reads all the numbers sequentially from the topmost cube and returns a string of common source code that it runs through exec, and so I want to write such source code but nothing significant turns out I can't realize the general message of the thought, maybe you could give me an idea of how to come to the realization of this idea? I wrote ChatGPT but it didn't really help, he misunderstands me:

```
import random 
 
def generate_random_source_code(moves): 
  # Creating an empty list to store the source code.
  source_code = [] 
  # We get the size of the side of the Rubik's cube from the last even number.
  side_size = moves[-1] // 2 
 
  # Going through the moves.
  for i in range(0, len(moves), 2): 
    # Checking to see if we are going beyond the list of moves.
    if i + 1 >= len(moves): 
      break 

    # We get the block number and the number of its movements. 
    block_number = moves[i] 
    num_moves = moves[i + 1] // 2 
 
    # Creating a displacement string for the block.
    move_string = "" 
    for j in range(num_moves): 
      move_string += f"block{block_number + j}.move()\n" 
 
    # Adding a string of moves to the source code.
    source_code.append(move_string) 
 
  # Creating a Rubik's cube reading string.
  read_string = "" 
  for i in range(side_size): 
    for j in range(side_size): 
      read_string += f"print(block{i * side_size + j}.value)\n" 
 
  # Returning the source code.
  return "".join(source_code) + read_string 
 
 
# Generating a random list of moves.
moves = [random.choice([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]) for i in range(10)] + [random.choice([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])] 
 
# We generate the source code.
source_code = generate_random_source_code(moves) 
 
# Executing the source code.
exec(source_code)
```

The second code:

```
import random 
 
def generate_random_source_code(moves): 
  source_code = "" 
 
  for i in range(0, len(moves), 2): 
    block_number = moves[i] 
    direction = moves[i + 1] 

    source_code += f"move_block({block_number}, {direction})\n" 
 
  return source_code 
 
 
moves = [random.randint(1, 9) for i in range(10)] 
 
source_code = generate_random_source_code(moves) 
 
print(source_code)
```

Maybe there is an idea how to fully implement this idea, how to write such code? It is necessary to think out the message of the thought to formalize the thought how to do this? Does anyone have any sketches at least?